# Express model size in pixels

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0

I have a SurfaceView object which will render a cube. Cube size might vary depending on some input expressed in pixels. For instance, there might be a task: resize the cube so that the front face is 200px wide. Given such a model representation in OpenGL like:

```
public final static float[] VERTICES = new float[]{
  // f 1 2 3 4
  0.49f, -0.49f, -0.49f,
  0.49f, -0.49f, 0.49f,
  -0.49f, -0.49f, 0.49f,
... and so on
```

, I'm not sure how to achieve it. Is it somehow related to frustum ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to:

- Project your vertices on the screen (using model * view * projection matrix)
- Find the bounding box of the projection
- Adjust your model transformation to get the size you need

to do it smoothly, I would simply animate the camera to get closer/futher to the cube and on each frame check the bounding box size to see if I should stop animating the camera.